# MatLab - 9.45 representation and round

Tags: matlab, rounding

```
>> a = 12.5 * 9.45

a =

     1.181250000000000e+02

>> round(a * 100) /100

ans =

     1.181200000000000e+02
```

The rounded value should be 118.13, not 118.12.

If you type 9.45 in MatLab command line, it can't be represented :

```
>> 9.45

ans =

   9.449999999999999
```

If I set the numeric format to short, the final result is the same.

```
>> a = 12.5 * 9.45

a =

  118.1250

>> round(a * 100) / 100

ans =

  118.1200
```

Can someone explain that? Any workaround?

Comment: Floating point numbers... You'll never get 100% accurate results with them

Comment: This is a floating point limitation and is a perfectly normal pain in the butt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like [John D'Errico's hpf class](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class-currently-in-beta-release).

This will give the result you are expecting

```
round(hpf('12.5') * hpf('9.45') * 100)/100
ans =
118.13


F = hpf('9.45')
F =
9.45
```

Comment: Actually, hpf also has a roundn tool in it, so you need not ever do the multiply and divide trick. roundn(hpf('12.5') * hpf('9.45'),-2) = 118.13

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got some settings that are messing with your output precision. It looks like your current settings want 15 decimal places(possibly `longG`)?, and with MATLABs floating point numbers you won't get 100% precision that far.

You can change the format of your display output, but the precision is going to be an issue to that level regardless.
[The relevant documentation.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/format.html)

Comment: My setting was set to long, but the final result is the same if i set it to short. my 118.12 should be 118.13. I'll update the question.